# Can't explain these results

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain to me why these results?

[image]

I know this is not a real problem, but I'm curious to know.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: What specifically are you wanting to know? There is an array an object an object converted to a string, an object and an array followed by 0...?

Comment: This is why I hate automatic type casting: so much potential to violate the [PoLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: @Precastic - Presumably why it is not commutative and the logic used for `+`

Comment: @scrappedcola i don't know how you googled `[] + {}` :)

Comment: "javascript array plus object" also helps i remember seeing this topic a couple of times in the past year ;)

Comment: @scrappedcola It still doesn't explain the first example's behavior. And although it *barely* answers the second example, the whole thing is dealing with `typeof` and how that's affecting the operation. That's far from a duplicate

Comment: @CD..: I love that talk :D

Comment: Very interesting, I'm gonna put it as favorite question (btw greetings from Morocco Mr @MajidL ;) )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This because `+` is meant to add numbers and strings, it's also the [unary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Plus.29).  It's also because `{}` is both an empty object and a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).

I can explain this.

```
[] + {}
```

Both are converted to strings.

```
[].toString() + {}.toString()
```

`[].toString()` is the same as `[].join('')`, and `{}.toString()` is `'[object Object]'`, so the first one is `[object Object]`.

The second one is more confusing.

```
{} + []
```

The `{}` here is *not* interpreted as an object, is interpreted as an empty block.  So the code inside is ran.  There's nothing inside, so it does nothing, then the next statement is ran:  `+[]`.  This converts the array to an int, which first converts it to a string than an it.

```
{} + [] => +[] => +([].toString()) => 0
```

If you put the `{}` in parenthesis, it'd be the same as the first.

```
({}) + [] => '[object Object]'
```

Answer (score 6):

From [here](http://cloverink.net/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the-wat-talk-for-codemash-2012/), related to [this](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

> 1. #### `[] + []`
>
>    When using the addition operator, both the left and right operands are converted to primitives first ([§11.6.1](http://cloverink.net/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the-wat-talk-for-codemash-2012/)). As per [§9.1](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat),
>      converting an object (in this case an array) to a primitive returns
>      its default value, which for objects with a valid `toString()` method
>      is the result of calling `object.toString()` ([§8.12.8](http://cloverink.net/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the-wat-talk-for-codemash-2012/)). For
>      arrays this is the same as calling `array.join()` ([§15.4.4.2][4]).
>      Joining an empty array results in an empty string, so step #7 of the
>      addition operator returns the concatenation of two empty strings,
>      which is the empty string.
> 2. #### `[] + {}`
>
>    Similar to `[] + []`, both operands are converted to primitives first. For "Object objects" (§15.2), this is again the result of
>      calling `object.toString()`, which for non-null, non-undefined objects
>      is `"[object Object]"` ([§15.2.4.2][5]).
> 3. #### `{} + []`
>
>    The `{}` here is not parsed as an object, but instead as an empty block ([§12.1][6], at least as long as you're not forcing that
>      statement to be an expression, but more about that later). The return
>      value of empty blocks is empty, so the result of that statement is the
>      same as `+[]`. The unary `+` operator ([§11.4.6][7]) returns
>      `ToNumber(ToPrimitive(operand))`. As we already know,
>      `ToPrimitive([])` is the empty string, and according to [§9.3.1][8],
>      `ToNumber("")` is 0.
> 4. #### `{} + {}`
>
>    Similar to the previous case, the first `{}` is parsed as a block with empty return value. Again, `+{}` is the same as
>      `ToNumber(ToPrimitive({}))`, and `ToPrimitive({})` is `"[object
>      Object]"` (see `[] + {}`). So to get the result of `+{}`, we have to
>      apply `ToNumber` on the string `"[object Object]"`. When following the
>      steps from [§9.3.1][9], we get `NaN` as a result:
>
>    > If the grammar cannot interpret the String as an expansion of *StringNumericLiteral*, then the result of [ToNumber][10] is **NaN**.
> 5. #### `Array(16).join("wat" - 1)`
>
>    As per [§15.4.1.1][11] and [§15.4.2.2][12], `Array(16)` creates a new array with length 16. To get the value of the argument to join,
>      [§11.6.2][13] steps #5 and #6 show that we have to convert both
>      operands to a number using `ToNumber`. `ToNumber(1)` is simply 1
>      ([§9.3][14]), whereas `ToNumber("wat")` again is `NaN` as per
>      [§9.3.1][15]. Following step 7 of [§11.6.2][16], [§11.6.3][17]
>      dictates that
>
>    > If either operand is **NaN**, the result is **NaN**.
>
>    So the argument to `Array(16).join` is `NaN`. Following §15.4.4.5 (`Array.prototype.join`), we have to call `ToString` on the argument,
>      which is `"NaN"` ([§9.8.1][18]):
>
>    > If *m* is **NaN**, return the String **`"NaN"`**.
>
>    Following step 10 of [§15.4.4.5][19], we get 15 repetitions of the concatenation of `"NaN"` and the empty string, which equals the result
>      you're seeing. When using `"wat" + 1` instead of `"wat" - 1` as
>      argument, the addition operator converts `1` to a string instead of
>      converting `"wat"` to a number, so it effectively calls
>      `Array(16).join("wat1")`.